# connecting to firebird db with c-plus-plus

Tags: c++, sql, firebird

I have firebird database. There are user-login and password. 
I want to connect to db with c++. What libriary can I use for doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Firebird C API directly, or if you are willing to live on the edge, the new Firebird 3.0 C++ API (currently in Alpha). There is also [IBPP](http://www.ibpp.org/) which is a C++ client for Firebird.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the SOCI library: [soci.sourceforge.net](http://soci.sourceforge.net/). I'm using it in my private project and I'm really satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's an ODBC driver: http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/odbc-driver/
So you can try to use with an ODBC Driver Manager: http://www.unixodbc.org/
A lot more C than C++ I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

If there's an ODBC driver as jsantander suggests in his answer, then  [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/) might be a viable C++ option.